# How to merge and deduplicate lists in Python efficiently?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, optimization, merge

I'd like to **merge and decuplicate** several lists in Python **efficiently**. There are 10 lists/pd.Series and each of them has approx. 200k *string* elements (They *DO NOT* have the same length). Each of them **has been sorted**. Lists have **~90% overlapping elements**. How can I **EFFICIENTLY** **MERGE** them and **DEDUPLICATE**?

I can use the following code to achieve merge and sort, but do we have a more efficient way? Performance is important here. (prefer not using Cython due to the overhead)

```
targetList = list()
for l in lists:
  targetList += l
targetList = list(set(targetList))
targetList = targetList.sort()
```

I also know that I can first **linearly** merge all the lists (order preserving), and linearly deduplicate with a hashset (actually the two steps can be merged).

However, there is no built-in function for such a lists merge and I fear my own code, w/ linear complexity, might bring in extra overhead and in turn become slower than NlogN algo with simple system built-in functions. I'm using Python3.9

I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-while-preserving-order) for deduplicate, but my question has many features that I think there is room for optimization.

Comment: Several ways come to mind. Which one is fastest might depend on the data. Hence realistic test data would be needed here so we can measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to achieve efficient merging and deduplication using the heapq.merge approach for merging sorted iterables and then applying a linear deduplication step.
There is an exemple :

```
import heapq

# Assuming 'lists' is a list of sorted lists/pd.Series
merged = list(heapq.merge(*lists))

# Linear deduplication
deduplicated = [merged[0]] + [value for prev, value in zip(merged, merged[1:]) if prev != value]
```

heapq.merge method avoids creating intermediate lists, providing good memory efficiency for large datasets. The overall time complexity is O(N * log(k)), where N is the total number of elements across all lists, and k is the number of input lists

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
import itertools
lists = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
list(dict.fromkeys(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lists)))    # dict.fromkeys will presever the order
```

Since, you already have sorted inner lists just element by element you will have values.

```
#output
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```